# Easy way to integrate over region in first quadrant between circles

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

The integral in question is $$ \iint\limits_D x \ dA$$ where $D$ is the region in the first quadrant lying between circles $x^2+y^2=4$ and $x^2+y^2=2x$.

Changing to polar coordinates I get $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \!\!\int_{2\cos{\theta}}^2 r^2\cos\theta \ dr \ d\theta = \frac{8}{3} \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos\theta-\cos^4\theta \ d\theta$$

Is there any way I can calculate this result without integrating $\cos^4\theta$? I wonder if there are any geometric solutions that avoid polar coordinates completely.

Edit: rectangular coordinates, too easy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D_1$ be the region described by $x^2+y^2 \le 4,\, x\ge 0,\, y \ge 0$ and $D_2$ the region $(x-1)^2+y^2 \le 1, \, y \ge 0$.
\begin{gather*}
\iint_{D}x\, dA = \iint_{D_1}x\, dA -\iint_{D_2}x\, dA =\\[2ex] \int_{0}^{2}\left(\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-y^2}}x\, dx\right)\, dy - \int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{1-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{1+\sqrt{1-y^2}}x\, dx\right)\, dy = \\[2ex]
\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2}(4-y^2)\, dy - \int_{0}^{1}2\sqrt{1-y^2}\, dy = 
\dfrac{8}{3}-\dfrac{\pi}{2}.
\end{gather*}
where the last integral can be interpreted as the area of a half unit circle.

Comment: I suppose the second area is also $\int_0^2 \int_0^{\sqrt{2x-x^2}} x \ dy \ dx$, is the "trick" the difference of squares?

Comment: It is also possible to evaluate the integral $I = \int_0^2\int_0^{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}x\,dy\,dx$ and avoid polar coordinates.

$
I = \int_0^2 x \sqrt{2x-x^2}\, dx = \int_0^2(x-1)\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}\, dx + \int_0^2 \sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}\, dx = 0 +\dfrac{\pi}{2}.
$

Answer (score 1):

With the fundamental identity and the double angle sine formula:

$\cos^4\theta=\cos^2\theta(1-\sin^2\theta)=\cos^2\theta-\frac{1}{2}\sin^2(2\theta)$

Further you might use the double angle cosine formula:

$\cos^2\theta=\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos(2\theta))$

$\sin^2(2\theta)=\frac{1}{2}(1-\sin(4\theta))$

... and you have reduced your integral to simple sine and cosine

Comment: This is still integrating $\cos^4\theta$ directly

Comment: Then you should have specified from the beginning that you don't want polar coordinates. The curves of the domain are too complicated to be solved with simple geometry. The domain and function itself are suitable for polar coordinates. You may integrate using rectangular coordinates, but I foresee way more complexity than $\cos^4(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

The integral 
$$
I = \displaystyle\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \cos^4 \theta = \displaystyle\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \cos^4 \left(\frac \pi 2 - \theta\right) = \displaystyle\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \sin^4 \theta
$$
Note then that 
$$
2I =  \displaystyle\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \cos^4 \theta + \sin^4 \theta
$$
Now, a little bit of insight, and we see that:
$$
\cos^4 \theta + \sin^4 \theta = \frac{\cos 4\theta + 3}4
$$
So it turns into:
$$
2I = \displaystyle\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \frac{\cos 4\theta + 3}4
$$
Surely this is an easier integral to solve. Upon request, I can derive the identity above.